# MERN app catch-all route - not fixing issue with receiving "Not found" on page refresh on pages other than home page

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mern

As the title describes I am currently working on a MERN app and have recently done a sort of "staging environment" deployment on onrender.com so that some family members (a graphic designer and copywriter" can take a look at what I've got so far and help me with some things. This is my first project so also my first time dealing with any problems outside of a local dev environment. The deployment went smoothly and the site renders and behaves as it should but the issue arrises when i go to refresh a page that is not the homepage. In this situation I receive an error message that the page is "Not found". If you would like to see for yourself the render link is https://sunshine-website-frontend-staging.onrender.com/.

My project directory is structured as follows:

Root

- api (models & index.js server file)
- public
- src (react files: components, pages, etc.)
- .gitignore
- package-lock.json
- package.json

When i deploy the app to render a build directory is created and is placed under the root (Root/build) and the index.html file from there is what should be served to a user that views the site. I believe the problem has to be with my index.js server file which is the following:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./models/User");
const Post = require("./models/Post");
const Poll = require("./models/Poll");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
const fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const secret = process.env.SALT_SECRET;

// const origin = "http://localhost:3000";
const origin = "https://sunshine-website-frontend-staging.onrender.com";

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: `${origin}` }));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/uploads", express.static(__dirname + "/uploads"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, username, password, role } = req.body;
  try {
    const userDoc = await User.create({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      username,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
      role,
    });
    res.json(userDoc);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});

app.get("/user/count", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userCount = await User.countDocuments();
    res.json({ count: userCount });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error fetching user count:", e);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ e: "An error occured while fetching user count" });
  }
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({ username });
  const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
  if (passOk) {
    jwt.sign(
      { username, id: userDoc._id, role: userDoc.role },
      secret,
      {},
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.cookie("token", token).json({
          id: userDoc._id,
          username,
          role: userDoc.role,
        });
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.status(400).json("wrong credentials");
  }
});

app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token) {
    res.status(200).json({});
    return;
  }
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(200).json({});
      return;
    }
    res.json(info);
  });
});

app.post("/post", uploadMiddleware.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  const { originalname, path } = req.file;
  const parts = originalname.split(".");
  const ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
  const newPath = path + "." + ext;
  fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

  const { title, summary, content } = req.body;

  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const postDoc = await Post.create({
      title,
      summary,
      content,
      cover: newPath,
      author: info.id,
    });
    res.json(postDoc);
  });
});

app.put("/post", uploadMiddleware.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  let newPath = null;
  if (req.file) {
    const { originalname, path } = req.file;
    const parts = originalname.split(".");
    const ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
    newPath = path + "." + ext;
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);
  }

  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const { id, title, summary, content } = req.body;
    const postDoc = await Post.findById(id);
    const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(postDoc.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id);
    if (!isAuthor) {
      return res.status(400).json("Invalid author");
    }
    await postDoc.updateOne({
      title,
      summary,
      content,
      cover: newPath ? newPath : postDoc.cover,
    });
    res.json(postDoc);
  });
});

app.get("/post", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find()
    .populate("author", ["username"])
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(20);
  res.json(posts);
});

app.get("/post/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const postDoc = await Post.findById(id).populate("author", ["username"]);
  res.json(postDoc);
});

app.post("/poll", async (req, res) => {
  const { title, intro, question, options } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    const pollDoc = await Poll.create({
      title,
      intro,
      question,
      options,
    });
    res.json(pollDoc);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});

app.get("/poll/latest", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Find the latest poll based on your logic (e.g., by creation date)
    const latestPoll = await Poll.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1);

    if (!latestPoll) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "No polls found" });
    }

    res.json(latestPoll);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching latest poll:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

app.post("/poll/latest/vote", async (req, res) => {
  const { optionId, userId } = req.body;

  try {
    // Find the latest poll based on your logic (e.g., by creation date)
    const latestPoll = await Poll.findOne().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1);

    if (!latestPoll) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "No polls found" });
    }

    const userVote = latestPoll.votedUsers.find(vote => vote.userId.toString() === userId);
    if (userVote) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User has already voted in this poll" });
    }

    const selectedOption = latestPoll.options.find((option) => option._id.toString() === optionId);
    if (!selectedOption) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid option" });
    }

    // Increment the vote count for the selected option
    selectedOption.votes += 1;

    latestPoll.votedUsers.push({ userId, optionId });

    // Save the updated poll with the new vote count
    await latestPoll.save();

    res.json({ message: "Vote recorded successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error recording vote:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

app.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("token", "").json("ok");
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const __dirname = path.resolve();
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => 
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running ...')
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

app.listen(port);
```

The catch-all route is set at the bottom which i believe is where it should be with the following block of code from the index.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const __dirname = path.resolve();
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => 
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running ...')
  });
}
```

I have tried many variations of the filepaths and filenames in this block of code and none seem to fix my issue of receiving not found when refreshing a page other than the homepage of my mern app. Am i missing something or is there another simple way to try and avoid the issue with the client side routing? or any other files that could be contributing to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a permanent solution or not because i may not be using render forever and i have no idea if other platforms provide a similar service but render has redirect/rewrite rules and you can set the catch-all there by setting source to "/*" and then setting destination to "/index.html" and then selecting rewrite from the dropdown. This seems to be working so hopefully this helps somebody.